# Run python subprocess waiting for a PIPE for stdinput without blocking the execution

Tags: python, subprocess, sudo

I'm trying to run a subprocess that submits an process of `openfortivpn`. This is my code:

```
  command = (f"sudo -S openfortivpn {config['address']}"
             f" --username {config['vpn_username']} -p {config['vpn_password']}"
             f" --trusted-cert {config['trusted_cert']}").split()
  vpn_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  vpn_output = vpn_process.communicate(input=config['sudo_passwd'].encode())[0]
```

The problem is that `openfortivpn` has to be run as root. Therefore, in order to send the password for sudo, I have to use the `-S` flag of `sudo` and a `PIPE`. The problem is that when I send the password via `communicate`, the Python execution is blocked. Note that I'm using `Popen` to spawn a suprobess precisely because it is supposedly non-blocking.

How can I avoid the blocking of the process caused by the PIPE? Ideally, I'd like that the `openfortivpn` is spawn in the terminal so I can keep running the script (which requires the VPN to be active).

More ideally still, I'd create a class that allows to me to use an environment which takes care of killing the process afterwards. Something such as:

```
with VPN():
    # do some fetching
```

Comment: Why would you use `.split()` to break a big string into a list instead of just building a list in the first place?

Comment: There are security issues in this code -- not as big as they would be if you used `shell=True`, but still significant (and likely to be exploitable in practice). Think about what happens if your vpn_username or vpn_password contains spaces; `split` will split pieces of the username or password into separate arguments. If `openfortivpn` can take an argument with a callback script to run or something else that can be leveraged into arbitrary code execution, that's a Very Big Deal.

Comment: `['sudo', '-S', 'openfortivpn', config['address'], '--username', config['username'], ...]` is much safer.

Comment: As for blocking -- `communicate()` is _inherently_ blocking; it's documented to block. If you don't want blocking, you shouldn't use `communicate()`, or should put it in a separate thread.

Comment: Fair enough, I can skip the `split()`. I used it because I find it more convenient to build the list that with many items surrounded by `'`. About the issue of my question, I know that `comunicate()` is the problem. But how can I remove it and still sending somehow the password for sudo?

Comment: By doing everything `communicate()` does in your own code :) -- it's not magic. Worst-case you need a little threading.

Comment: `vpn_process.stdin.write(password); vpn_process.stdin.close()` manages the write and shuts down stdin when done. The tricky part is avoiding deadlocks, f/e, if the program tries to write logs to stdout or stderr _before_ it reads from stdin. That's where threading comes in handy: If you have a different thread reading stdout and stderr, then the ordering between when the program writes logs vs when it reads input is moot. But since you don't have `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` you don't need that presently.

Comment: Security concerns aside, this strikes me as a usecase for [pyexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html).  I second everything else said though about passing unsanitised input around, but pyexpect is worth knowing about.

Comment: @2e0byo, ...I have a whole rant about "unsanitized" input being considered a problem in situations where the real problem is _that the logic that input is passed into is vulnerable_. Trying to protect a system's boundaries is a losing battle -- it's like how folks eventually gave up on relying on firewalls for networking and moved towards zero-trust. The industry needs to do the same thing for complex data within systems, relying on sanitization only when there's no other way.

Comment: @2e0byo, ... (Part of why sanitization is a losing battle is that it's context-dependent; sanitizing data for Context X -- say, HTML -- may not make that same data safe to use in Context Y -- be that PostScript or SQL or who-knows-what-else; better to ensure that your Context X code and Context Y code make no assumptions about their inputs than to place the onus on the input code).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
    subprocess.call(["sudo","openfortivpn", f"{args.ip}:{args.port}", "-u", f"{args.username}", "-p", f"{args.password}", "--otp", f"{args.auth}", "--trusted-cert", f"{args.cert}"], shell=False)
```

i have a medium post about in this topic. You can read from [this link](https://medium.com/@bekirduran/vpn-usage-on-ubuntu-with-openfortivpn-72b4cdd91401) and you can reach code from [this link](https://github.com/bekirduran/openfortivpn_starter/blob/main/VpnStarter.py).I hope its works for you!